# How to update all similar DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild, selectors-api

I am trying to append to two `<nav>`s. But only second is updated. What am I missing?
I tried `Array.from(socialMediaIcons).forEach` and `for` loop, but with the same result.

```js
var socialMedia = {
  facebook: 'http://facebook.com/xyz',
  twitter: 'http://twitter.com/xyz',
  flickr: 'http://flickr.com/xyz',
  youtube: 'http://youtube.com/xyz'
};

(() => {
  const socialMediaIcons = document.querySelectorAll(".socialmediaicons");
  const ulElement = document.createElement("ul");

  Object.keys(socialMedia).forEach(key => {
    const liElement = document.createElement("li");
    const imageElement = document.createElement("img");
    imageElement.src = `./images/${key}.png`;
    liElement.appendChild(imageElement);
    ulElement.appendChild(liElement);

  });

  socialMediaIcons.forEach(element => {
    element.appendChild(ulElement)
  });

})(socialMedia)
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Social Media Icons</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<nav class="socialmediaicons">Add images below</nav>

<h1>Welcome</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos, praesentium, reprehenderit, eos, eligendi iure eaque culpa vel distinctio quibusdam amet laudantium aut ea fugit magni quidem iste fugiat sunt voluptate.</p>

<nav class="socialmediaicons">Add images below</nav>

<script src="script.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the expected outcome?

Comment: I want to append ulElement that I created to both `<nav class="socialmediaicons">Add images below</nav>`. Right now it is appended to only second one.

Comment: The problem is that any one element can only be in one place at once. `appendChild` does not copy the elements, it moves the reference (or something similar). So you need a new separate `ul` for each nav.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) if given an already existing child will *move it* to a new parent:

```js
document.getElementById("click_me").addEventListener("click", function() {
  const child = document.getElementById("move_me");

  document.getElementById("two").appendChild(child);
});
```

```css
#one {
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 50px;
}

#two {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <p id="move_me">Hello world</p>
</div>

<div id="two"></div>

<button id="click_me">Click to move</button>
```

So, when you get to

```js
socialMediaIcons.forEach(element => {
  element.appendChild(ulElement)
});
```

You add the *existing* `ulElement` to each of the `socialMediaIcons` elements, which is moving it from one to the next.

You can ensure you have different elements if you create a fresh `<ul>` for each of `socialMediaIcons`:

```js
var socialMedia = {
  facebook: 'http://facebook.com/xyz',
  twitter: 'http://twitter.com/xyz',
  flickr: 'http://flickr.com/xyz',
  youtube: 'http://youtube.com/xyz'
};

((socialMedia) => {
  const socialMediaIcons = document.querySelectorAll(".socialmediaicons");

  socialMediaIcons.forEach(element => {
    //creating and populating the <ul> during the iteration
    const ulElement = document.createElement("ul");
    
    Object.keys(socialMedia).forEach(key => {
      const liElement = document.createElement("li");
      const imageElement = document.createElement("img");
      imageElement.src = `./images/${key}.png`;
      liElement.appendChild(imageElement);
      ulElement.appendChild(liElement);

    });
  
    element.appendChild(ulElement)
  });

})(socialMedia)
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Social Media Icons</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<nav class="socialmediaicons">Add images below</nav>

<h1>Welcome</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos, praesentium, reprehenderit, eos, eligendi iure eaque culpa vel distinctio quibusdam amet laudantium aut ea fugit magni quidem iste fugiat sunt voluptate.</p>

<nav class="socialmediaicons">Add images below</nav>

<script src="script.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)

> The Node.cloneNode() method returns a duplicate of the node on which
>   this method was called.

```js
var socialMedia = {
  facebook: 'http://facebook.com/xyz',
  twitter: 'http://twitter.com/xyz',
  flickr: 'http://flickr.com/xyz',
  youtube: 'http://youtube.com/xyz'
};

(() => {
  const socialMediaIcons = document.querySelectorAll(".socialmediaicons");
  const ulElement = document.createElement("ul");

  Object.keys(socialMedia).forEach(key => {
    const liElement = document.createElement("li");
    const imageElement = document.createElement("img");
    imageElement.src = `./images/${key}.png`;
    liElement.appendChild(imageElement);
    ulElement.appendChild(liElement);

  });

  socialMediaIcons.forEach(element => {
    element.appendChild(ulElement.cloneNode(true))
  });

})(socialMedia)
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Social Media Icons</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<nav class="socialmediaicons">Add images below</nav>

<h1>Welcome</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos, praesentium, reprehenderit, eos, eligendi iure eaque culpa vel distinctio quibusdam amet laudantium aut ea fugit magni quidem iste fugiat sunt voluptate.</p>

<nav class="socialmediaicons">Add images below</nav>

<script src="script.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```